# Java convert XML to YAML

Tags: java, yaml

I need to convert a XML File to YAML.
I could not find anything helpful on Google.
Is there any similar API like the json in java to convert a XML file to YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jackson, it supports XML and YAML (and also JSON, CSV and more).

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml

Or if it's more easy to understand for you, take two steps: XML -> JSON , JSON -> YAML. Because there are lot's of tutorials for XML -> JSON and YAML is pretty similar to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Other than json, you can use TestNG to convert XML to YAML,

http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Converter.html

http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/03/testng-60

Answer (score 0):

You may combine [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) and [snakeyaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/default/) libraries.

Steps:

- Read xml file to map.
- Generate yml file from map.

  ```
  import com.github.underscore.lodash.Xml;
  import java.io.StringWriter;
  import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

  Object result = Xml.fromXml(xml);
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  yaml.dump(result, stringWriter);
  String yaml = stringWriter.toString();
  ```